# Parsing XML with Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

Hi I am new to Jquery and struggling with parsing XML. 
I have a search box in my form that returns the results of a sql search when the user has entered the first few letters . this string is then searched with a php file and the results are returned in the form of an xml file. The problem is that I need to uniquely identify each name and id returned and then to be able to access a specific name/id set. so that this one item is shown on my form. 
The code (I thought) would return a list of all the the names but this seems to be in just one string. Can anybody please help me with accessing individual xml elements . I have included the xml file at the bottom , thanks for any help

```
        // JQ - ajax  
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
             $.ajax({
                      type: "GET", 
                      url: "search_action.php?" + string ,
                      dataType: "xml",
                      success: disxml ,

                 });


        })
        }

         function disxml(data){

        $(data).find('results').each(function() {  

        var name      = $(this).find('name').text();   
        var cus_id    = $(this).find('id').text(); 


        })
```

The XML File

```
      <results>

      <name>
      The porter grp
      </name>
      <id>
      548930
      </id>

      <name>
      ADI UK
      </name>
      <id>
      986565
      </id>

      <name>
      Fireled
      </name>
      <id>
      549899
      </id>

      <name>
      JCK Rec LTD
      </name>
      <id>
      548442
      </id>

      </results>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to change the XML schema to include a result node containing the name and id elements.

```
<results>
  <result>
      <name>
      The porter grp
      </name>
      <id>
      548930
      </id>
  </result>
  <result>
      <name>
      ADI UK
      </name>
      <id>
      986565
      </id>
  </result>

</results>
```

Your jQuery code should then do something like

```
function disxml(data){

        $(data).find('result').each(function() {  

        var name      = $(this).find('name').text();   
        var cus_id    = $(this).find('id').text(); 


        })
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of [json](http://www.json.org/)?

Javascript can handle json beautifully. So my suggestion is that you serialize your data to json instead of XML and feed this to javascript.

Looky [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) for the how.